# JFrame is empty

Tags: java, swing

I'm working on a Java HW and faced this problem. Even though everything seems to be coded correctly, I'm getting blank frame in the end. I'm guessing it has something to do with this part in the driver program:

`frame.getContentPane().add(new RandomPanel());`

Here is my main program:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.Random;

import javax.swing.*;

public class RandomPanel extends JPanel
{
  private JButton randButton; 
  private JLabel label;

  public void NamePanel()
  {
    JPanel primary = new JPanel();

    randButton = new JButton("Whats my name?");

    ButtonListener listener = new ButtonListener();
    randButton.addActionListener(listener);

    label = new JLabel("Displaying random number");


    setBackground(Color.pink);
    add(label);
    add(randButton);
  }

  class ButtonListener implements ActionListener 
  {

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
    {

      label.setText(  new Integer(new Random().nextInt(100) + 1).toString() );
    }

  }

}
```

And driver program:

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class RandomPick
{

    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("RandomPick");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        frame.getContentPane().add(new RandomPanel());

        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to invoke `namePanel` to add the components to the frame.

```
RandomPanel randomPanel = new RandomPanel();
randomPanel.namePanel();
frame.add(randomPanel);
```

but you may have intended to use the method as a constructor

```
public RandomPanel() {
```

which would mean that the method call would not be necessary

Comment: is correct @user1743703.  I just made the change and ran the code.  If you for some reason didn't want to change that to be the constructor then you would need to modify your code in `main()` to be something more like this: `RandomPanel p = new RandomPanel();`, `p.NamePanel()`, `frame.getContentPane().add(p);`

Comment: Sounds like an unrelated issue, probably something not imported